# Is it possible to install signtool.exe without admin rights?

Tags: sdk, signtool

I'm trying to make my build file a bit more automatic, so that it signs automatically, but I don't have signtool.exe file, because I don't have the Windows SDK/KIT files. I could probably install the SDK some sneaky way without admin, but I don't have much space left for it, so I'd like to get only the .exe file. I've only got around 2GB of space, ***and*** I don't have admin rights on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signtool.exe is a standalone executable, it doesn't need the SDK to run. So you could install it on your home computer (or in a virtual machine) and bring signtool.exe at work on a USB key.